# Boot map is full command: sudo apt-get autoremove does not work: see text

Tags: boot

```
jp59@JP59:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for jp59: 
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
0 opgewaardeerd, 0 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 9 niet opgewaardeerd.
3 niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Na deze bewerking zal er 0 B extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Instellen van linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic (3.19.0-25.26) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subproces post-installation script geïnstalleerd  gaf een foutwaarde 1 terug
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic is afhankelijk van linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic; maar:
  Pakket linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic is nog niet geconfigureerd.

dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-image-generic (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van linux-generic:
 linux-generic is afhankelijk van linux-image-generic (= 3.19.0.25.24); maar:
  Pakket linux-image-generic is nog niet geconfigureerd.

dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-generic (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding aangeeft dat de fout het gevolg is van een eerdere mislukking.
                                           Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding aangeeft dat de fout het gevolg is van een eerdere mislukking.
      Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jp59@JP59:~$
```

Comment: You're need to translate the error. If you don't, your question will be put 'on hold' until you do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer;
I've selected these texts:

linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.19.0.25.24); But:
  Package linux-image-generic isńt configured yet.

And, the last lines of the message after the command :( sudo-apt-get autoremove) :

Mistakes foud during processing ( installation ? ) of:
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Does this give a better idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone say I think you should try to translate your output since it isn't wide understood.

We need more info, but what could be happening is not that boot is full but your nodes are.

Try

```
df -i
```

To see what is the real problem.
Cheers